# Sum Up Values from the Same Date Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am looking to sum up the values from different cells which occur on the same date. I wish to use the dates from column E and the values from column B.

For example- date 11/09/2022 should add up to 14,919.8 but on the formula I used from a previous answer it results in 36945.4. What do I need to do to change this?

I have tried to use previous answers to resolve this issue but was unsuccessful.

The sheet can be found here if you wish to play around with it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11RjGeyOIpGS2q7fDmG0bgniQxibCGe9f-xHi-tmVexc/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({E3:E, B3:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer- the only issue with this is that it provides the data in a new column sorted from oldest to newest. When I try to sort this from Z-A much of the data disappears. Do you know any solutions to this?

Comment: @hogballs96 try: `=QUERY({E3:E, B3:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by Col1 desc
  label sum(Col2)''")`